# How to solve a matrix from matrix vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

I have a matrix-vector multiplication code to run
$$
b^TAb=c
$$
where $b$ is a vector to get a scalar number $c$.

However, the construction of square matrix $A$ is very expensive, so I wonder is it possible to compute the matrix $A$ if we know both $b$ and the constant $c$ to reduce the computation time. Because in my case I can approximate the $c$ value beforehand.

I tried right multiplying a $b.T$ to the equation and got
$$
b^TA=\frac{c}{|b|^2}b^T
$$
so one very trivial solution is that $A$ is a diagonal matrix with $\dfrac{c}{|b|^2}$ the diagonal elements. I do not know how to obtain the general solution for this question.
What techniques should be used in solving for matrix $A$? And what does the complete solution set of the matrix $A$ look like?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for letting me know that!

Comment: Be careful. $bb^\top$ is *not* $|b|^2$. It is a big square matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin ah, indeed I made a mistake here. So instead of $|b|^2$ it should be a inverse of a big square matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a single value of $c$ associated with some vector $b$ you do not have enough information to construct $A$.

The quadratic form $b^\intercal A b $ involves the sum of multiple products and the elements of $A$ act as the coefficients. The only thing you can take advantage is that usually, $A$ is symmetric which means you only need to determine $n (n+1)/2$ terms to fully define it.

In the simplest form of $A$ as 2×2 matrix, you expand out the calculation to get

$$ c = \pmatrix{b_1 \\ b_2}^\top \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{12} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{b_1 \\ b_2} $$

$$ c= A_{11} b_1^2 + 2 A_{12} b_1 b_2 + A_{22} b_2^2 $$

So you are asking if you can determine $A_{11}$, $A_{12}$ and $A_{22}$ from the above given $c$, $b_1$ and $b_2$?

The answer is **no** since you have 1 linear equation (in terms of $A$ terms) and three unknowns.

You would need at least three conditions (call them A,B,C) to form the following set of equations

$$ \begin{aligned}
c^A & = A_{11} (b_1^A)^2 + 2 A_{12} b_1^A b_2^A + A_{22} (b_2^A)^2 \\
c^B & = A_{11} (b_1^B)^2 + 2 A_{12} b_1^B b_2^B + A_{22} (b_2^B)^2 \\
c^C & = A_{11} (b_1^C)^2 + 2 A_{12} b_1^C b_2^C + A_{22} (b_2^C)^2 \\
\end{aligned} $$

to be solved for $A_{11}$, $A_{12}$ and $A_{23}$ as a 3×3 system.

Comment: I'd just like to clarify for the original poster that if their $A$ should not be symmetric, there is even less they can learn about $A$: no matter how many $b$s and $c$s they have at their disposal, the product $b^TAb$ is only responsive to the symmetric part $A^+ \equiv (A + A^T)/2$ of $A$ in the sense that $\forall b: b^T A b = b^T A^+ b$. Therefore, using the product, one cannot extract any information about the antisymmetric part $A^-\equiv (A-A^T)/2$ (to state the obvious: $A = A^+ + A^-$).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The matrix $A$ by construction is all positive and symmetric, I forgot to mention that. And I think from the answer above it is not possible to retrive the $A$ from the quadratic form equation